# Multiple GSON @SerializedName per field?

Tags: java, json, gson

Is there any way in Gson to map multiple JSON fields to a single Java object member variable?

Let's say I have a Java class...

```
public class MyClass {
    String id;
    String name;
}
```

I want to use this single class with two different services. However, these two services differ in how they return their data...

```
{ "id": 2341, "person": "Bob" }
```

... and ...

```
{ "id": 5382, "user": "Mary" }
```

... respectively.

Is there any way to map both the `"person"` and `"user"` fields in the JSON string to the `name` field in the Java object?

(Note: I only ever need to convert from JSON string to Java object - never the other way around.)

Comment: Here is simple and Perfect explanation  https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-model-annotations-multiple-deserialization-names-with-serializedname

Answer (score 307):

In October 2015, **Gson version 2.4** ([changelog](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-24)) added the ability to use alternate/multiple names for `@SerializedName` when deserializing. No more custom TypeAdapter needed!

**Usage:**

java

```
@SerializedName(value="name", alternate={"person", "user"})
```

kotlin

```
@SerializedName(value="name", alternate= ["person", "user"])
```

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html

Comment: Here is simple and Perfect explanation  https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-model-annotations-multiple-deserialization-names-with-serializedname

Comment: while I add alternate , it shows error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class, declares multiple JSON fields named

Comment: It's worth noting that if the JSON has both fields, the order of preference does not seem to be honoured and its possible the alternate is selected over the main name. 

So if you want to use to to select a field and have an alternate to fall back in if its not set then you may not get the expected result.

Answer (score 32):

for **Kotlin** fans

```
@SerializedName(value="name", alternate= ["person", "user"])
```

Answer (score 28):

It is not supported to define multiple `@SerializedName` annotations to a field at Gson.

**Reason:**  By default Deserialization is managed with a LinkedHashMap and the keys are defined by incoming json's field names (not the custom class's field names or the serializedNames) and there is a one to one mapping. You can see the implementation(how deserialization works) at `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` class's inner class `Adapter<T>`'s `read(JsonReader in)` method.

**Solution:**
You can write a custom [TypeAdapter](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html) which handles `name`, `person` and `user` json tags and maps them to name field of your custom class `MyClass`:

```
class MyClassTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<MyClass> {

    @Override
    public MyClass read(final JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        final MyClass myClassInstance = new MyClass();

        in.beginObject();
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            String jsonTag = in.nextName();
            if ("id".equals(jsonTag)) {
                myClassInstance.id = in.nextInt();
            } else if ("name".equals(jsonTag) 
                    || "person".equals(jsonTag)
                    || "user".equals(jsonTag)) {
                myClassInstance.name = in.nextString();
            }
        }
        in.endObject();

        return myClassInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(final JsonWriter out, final MyClass myClassInstance)
            throws IOException {
        out.beginObject();
        out.name("id").value(myClassInstance.id);
        out.name("name").value(myClassInstance.name);
        out.endObject();
    }
}
```

**Test case:**

```
    String jsonVal0 = "{\"id\": 5382, \"user\": \"Mary\" }";
    String jsonVal1 = "{\"id\": 2341, \"person\": \"Bob\"}";

    final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(MyClass.class, new MyClassTypeAdapter());
    final Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    MyClass myClassInstance0 = gson.fromJson(jsonVal0, MyClass.class);
    MyClass myClassInstance1 = gson.fromJson(jsonVal1, MyClass.class);

    System.out.println("jsonVal0 :" + gson.toJson(myClassInstance0));
    // output: jsonVal0 :{"id":5382,"name":"Mary"}

    System.out.println("jsonVal1 :" + gson.toJson(myClassInstance1));
    // output: jsonVal1 :{"id":2341,"name":"Bob"}
```

[Examples about TypeAdapters.](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-typeadapter-example/)

**Edit 2016.04.06 :** As @Mathieu Castets has written at his answer, it is supported now. (That is the correct answer for this question.)

> **public abstract String[] alternate** 
>   Returns: the alternative names of
>   the field when it is deserialized 
> **Default:** {}

Comment: Here is simple and Perfect explanation  https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-model-annotations-multiple-deserialization-names-with-serializedname

Answer (score 12):

For KOTLIN i used below but doesn't work

```
@SerializedName(value="name", alternate= ["person", "user"])
```

so i edited it and here it works fine!!

```
@SerializedName(value="name", alternate= arrayOf("person", "user"))
```