# Generic approach to deserialize Json to Object

Tags: java, json, parsing, generics, gson

This is a kind of specific question and I couldn't get any information on this topic in the javadoc of [Gson](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.4).

---

Currently, I'm trying to parse an Json(1)`{ "foo":"bar", "bar":"foo" }` to an Object `Entity`. Normally I would map these values to the `Entity` Object with the fields `foo` and `bar`, however I'd like to be more *independent* from the API.

---

For (1) I'd have

```
public class Entity {
String foo;
String bar;
}
```

But if we test another Endpoint the resulting Json (2) would look like

`{ "notFoo":"bar", "notBar":"foo" }`

which makes my previous constructed `Entity` *useless*, and I'd need to create a new Class with the respective fields for that.

---

So my actual question is:

1. Is there a **generic** (more generic than my example) approach to 
   push the Json into a `GenericEntity` -> `g.fromJson(response.getBody(),GenericEntity.class);` that every *field* of the json will be successfully mapped, even when using different Endpoints?
2. Alternatively, are there other dependencies which support that out of the box?

Comment: How you want to be more generic if you NEED to know the type of the object to assign on?

Comment: You will never found yourself doing ```Object result = g.fromJson(body);``` unless you don't need to use the properties of the object

Comment: Actually this may work @MarcosVasconcelos 

`public class Entity {

    Object foo;
    Object bar;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have a deserialisation problem, you have a problem of not knowing how to represent possibly heterogeneous data.

There is no point of saying it should be `Object` as it should definitely be some type downstream of `Object`, possibly more than one. Solve this problem first: define all types that you may want to use for all use cases and then you will most likely see how to solve the deserialisation problem.

Surely, for any JSON text defined between `{...}` you can always go for `Map<String, Object>` where `Object` is one of:

- further `Map<String, Object>` where `Object` follows these rules
- `List<Object>` where `Object` follows these rules
- `String`
- one of atomic types or their boxed values

With the above rules you can represent more or less everything and you can write `Gson` deserialisers to deliver you those types based on the JSON type of each node (while iterating via the JSON tree). However, it is not really clear what use could you make of such a heterogenous untyped data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the annotation `@serializedName` as written in [Multiple GSON @SerializedName per field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707728/multiple-gson-serializedname-per-field?answertab=votes#tab-top). But the schema must be the same, you only have alternatives to key name.

Comment: Thanks! This is already helping me slightly, but I'm still kind of *(but at least less)* restricted.

Comment: Yeah, it's not the greatest feature but helps with the same schema

If this anwer was useful for you, please accept my answer :)