# I want to use the same model in retrofit for different type of response from API

Tags: android, api, jackson, retrofit

I have two APIs with outer model same, So have a made a model class for the outer model (ResponseModel) and for result key, I have made a class called ResultModel, so i may able to write all the possible response that may come over the result key

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public  class ResponseModel {
    @JsonProperty("code")
    private Integer code;

    @JsonProperty("message")
    private String message;

    @JsonProperty("result")
    private List<ResultModel> result;
}
```

Here I have added the possible response in the ResultModel
result key will give country list or state list

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ResultModel {

    private Country country;

    private State state;

}
```

CountryList API 1 Result

```
{ 
    "code" :102
    "message" : "message string"
    "result" : [ 
                 { "id" : 1, "name": "hello" },  
                 { "id" : 2, "name": "world" }]
}
```

StateList API 2 Result

```
{ 
    "code" :101
    "message" : "message test"
    "result" : [ 
                 { "id" : 1, "name": "hello", "code" :1001 },  
                 { "id" : 2, "name": "world", "code" :1002 }]
}
```

This structure i followed to reuse the outer model. But its not working

Is there anyway to reuse the ResponseModel without creating each class for country and state.

Comment: Just add name field to ResultModel?

Comment: In ResultModel there may be country or state. So we cannot add the name field "result" for both the variables

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36058278/3735097

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your implementation is that you are building in a wrong way the object, with the current classes you are waiting a json like this:

```
{ 
    "code" :102
    "message" : "message string"
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "country" : { "id" : 1, "name": "hello" }, 
            "state" : { "id" : 2, "name": "world", "code" :1002 }
        }
     ]
}
```

A better option, is to use Generics like this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public  class ResponseModel<T> {
  @JsonProperty("code")
  private Integer code;

  @JsonProperty("message")
  private String message;

  @JsonProperty("result")
  private List<T> result;
}
```

And then you can specify on your implementation the type of object that you spect:

```
ResponseModel<Country>
ResponseModel<State>
```

And the class ResultModel will be not necessary any more.

Comment: Actually you can make the attribute like a Generic, because no always will be a list,  @JsonProperty("result")
  private T result;

Answer (score 0):

you require below class architecuture..

```
data class WebResponse<T>(
    val code: Int,
    val message: String,
    val result: List<T>
) {}
```

and call your service like

```
@GET("/countryList")
fun getCountries(): Call<WebResponse<CountryEntity>>

@GET("/stateList")
fun getStateList(): Call<WebResponse<StateEntitiy>>
```

Comment: @Frankenstein if my question helps you. Kindly accept it